# Cordova Android platform - ant installation not recognized

Tags: java, android, cordova, ant, ionic-framework

I keep recieving the following error when attempting to add a platform to a cordova project.

ERROR: executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path.

I have added my **JAVA_HOME**, **ANT_HOME** and **ANDROID_HOME** (both \tools and \platform-tools) environment variables and can confirm they are all installed correctly be executing  'java', 'ant -version' and 'android' commands in my console and getting responses.

Right now, I have the above mentioned environment variables as both User and System variables, but have also tried just having them configured as System variables.

Ant version: 1.9.2 
java: jdk1.8.0_11

I'm quite stumped right now because everything seems to be configured/installed correctly. Is there a specific location I should install/un-zip these components?

Comment: where is the error message come from? if it is a shell, you can try to open a new shell? if it is some IDE, you can try to restart the IDE

Comment: Yep, it's coming from the shell. Whenever I make changes to my environment variables I always close/open a new shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to show full path to bin folder of ANT. see for the variable name path, edit it. add one of the following to the end of it's value.

Suppose your ant folder is in d drive like this `D:\ant` then your `ANT_HOME` value should be `D:\ant`. Then add this to your path variable

```
%ANT_HOME%\bin
```

OR add the full path like

```
D:\ant\bin
```